# MS Access Error on Delete Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Please see the query below

```
DELETE [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID
FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012]
WHERE ((([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID)=
   (SELECT Min([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID) AS MinOfID
   FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012]
   GROUP BY [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].Title
   HAVING (((count([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID))>1)))
));
```

I am getting the following error

> At most one record can be returned by this sub query.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this query:

```
DELETE [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID
FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012]
WHERE ((([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID) IN
   (SELECT Min([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID) AS MinOfID
   FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012]
   GROUP BY [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].Title
   HAVING (((count([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID))>1)))
));
```

Comment: some explanation is welcome! code only answers are not the best

Comment: Replacing In with = did the trick, Thanks Andrea but the data is huge so access crashed but I think this is the right query. can I delete records using something like `DELETE (SELECT Min([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID) AS MinOfID
   FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012]
   GROUP BY [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].Title
   HAVING (((count([All Uploaded parts UK in 2012].ID))>1)) ) AS EXPR1 FROM [All Uploaded parts UK in 2012] ` I think it would be faster.